# can php be used on Tor

Tags: help

I have set up a hidden service site on Tor and haven't had issues. I decided to add a forum section to the site to allow discussion.  I figured the easiest option would be to use phpbb with the LEMP stack. Meaning I have ubuntu server, nginx, mysql, and php5-fpm installed.  When I open the site through firefox I can open the bulletin board no problem but when I try and open it through the Tor browser it tries to download a file instead. Is this an issue with using php or do I need to do something else to get it to work on the Tor browser?

I hope I explained my issue well enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Tor is totally agnostic to the data sent over it, this is a server configuration problem. PHP is executed at the server side, before the data is sent over the network, so it won't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was a config problem but didn't want to keep messing around with it and wasting my time if that wasn't the case. I just thought it was weird it opened in Firefox but not the TOR browser but I guess that is a hint to what my config issue is since Firefox was accessing through my local network and TOR wasn't I believe.

Comment: Check that both vhosts are treated equally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was configuration of the server and had nothing to do with the Tor browser.  I had server information in the nginx.conf file and also in the virtual host configurations.  I just commented out the server information in the nginx.conf file and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should have all your dot-onions to be forward-and-back resolvable via DNS/resolver on your NGinx machine. Use `/etc/hosts` and 127.0.0.[2-xxx] addresses for it on dedicated localhost/loopback interfaces. It's simple, secure and very fuckup-proof. I can provide you with configs if you need.

UPDATE: config files and HOWTO

in `/etc/network/interfaces` you should replace `lo loopback` string with this block:

```
auto lo lo:0 lo:1 lo:2
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo:0 inet static
    address 127.0.0.2
    netmask 255.0.0.0

iface lo:1 inet static
    address 127.0.0.3
    netmask 255.0.0.0

iface lo:2 inet static
    address 127.0.0.4
    netmask 255.0.0.0
```

you can add more if you wish. Next, in `/etc/hosts` use :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.2 hs1.onion
127.0.0.3 hs2.onion
127.0.0.4 hs3.onion
```

and use your webserver to bind by-ip **and by dedicated-per-vhost user** your HS virtual hosts. In firewall use any kind of stuff you prefer to block by IP **and** by user any communications except 127.0.0.1 <-> 127.0.0.X to prevent any network leaks possible.

If you're using non-local HS setup - it's OK and it's quite obvious in case of opening "an entry point" for existing server in Tor network(like Facebook did it for it's website) - then you can consider using local ISC Bind setup with reverse and forward lookups. The purpose is *to make sure that hs1.onion resolves via *system libs*, not the cmdline tools you're used to lookup, because they're using DNS queries explicitly. The desired result is like this:

- `perl -MSocket -le '$a=shift; $x=gethostbyname $a; print inet_ntoa($x);' hs1.onion` into 127.0.0.2
- `perl -MSocket -le '$a=inet_aton(shift); $_=gethostbyaddr $a, AF_INET; print' 127.0.0.2` returns ns1.onion.

Some checklist for localhost-names:

- **Check NSS switch** like this: `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep "^hosts:"` and make sure `files` is set first. If not, edit it and in line starting with "hosts:" put it on a first place.
- **Fix/check host.conf** like this `cat /etc/host.conf` and add string `order hosts,bind` if missing or put `hosts` at the first place right after the `order`. It's one string too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sounds pretty complicated to me though. I'll be honest I don't really know what I am doing. I have just been pulling stuff from forums or using default settings and managed to get things working. Probably not a very secure setup but I am not that worried about it. Though I do want to learn more about it so I will look into what you said. If you can provide those config files it would be a helpful start.